# Customize Select box

Tags: html

The text in select box is being truncated after selecting the required option.but i want the complete text.i have tried this code, and i don't want to increase the width.i will be great if the remaining text show in next line

```html
    <select style="width:100px;" id='noOfUser' name='noOfUser' class="accordion_inner">
   <option value='0'>&nbsp;Select No of Users</option>
   <option value='100'>All Users in the city of mumbai</option>
   <option value='70'>70% Users in the city of mumbai</option>
   <option value='50'>50% Users in the city of mumbai</option>
   <option value='30'>30% Users in the city of mumbai</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I don´t think what you're asking is possible just with html and css..

Comment: yes, it is possible, use word-wrap property of css

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `white-space` property which controls how text is handled. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0rkmgw13/ .
Unfortunately, this will not work in IE http://caniuse.com/#search=white-space , and in Firefox on my PC (v. 34.0.5) this didn't work as well, nor with prefix, as suggested, or without it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for tour response, but white-space did not work here.
I have found the solution,word-wrap: break-word; solves the problem

Select No of Users
      All Users in the city of mumbai
      70% Users in the city of mumbai
      50% Users in the city of mumbai
      30% Users in the city of mumbai